# Generate Fixed Length Feed File in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have received a requirement to generate a fixed length feed file containing user information from the application database 
and share the file with another system.

In fixed length, it has been told that each column will have x character length followed by the next column 
of say y character length and so on until the last column to be fetched. The total row length has to be 2900.

I have managed to draft a SQL file which looks something like the below code snippet:

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET LINESIZE 2900
SET PAGESIZE 0

SPOOL user_feed.txt

SELECT extract_date
  || user_name
  || user_email
  || user_sys
  || user_grpname "USER_ROW"
FROM
  (SELECT RPAD(DECODE(extract_date,'',' ',trim(extract_date)),26) user_name,
    RPAD(DECODE(name,'',' ',trim(name)),50) user_name,
    RPAD(DECODE(email,'',' ',trim(email)),75) user_email,
    RPAD(DECODE(sys_name,'',' ',trim(sys_name)),10) user_sys,
    RPAD(DECODE(group_name,'',' ',trim(group_name)),26) user_grpname
    --....so on (picking all columns from below query)
  FROM
    (SELECT CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP) extract_date,
      u.name,
      u.email,
      g.sys_name,
      g.group_name --(....so on)
    FROM user_tab u,
      user_grp g
    WHERE u.userid = g.userid
    )
  );

SPOOL OFF;
```

When I spool small amount of data the fixed length file is produced, but when the source tables contain large number of rows, the spool file does not preserve the formatting, the data gets mixed.

1. Can anyone please suggest how I can overcome this issue?
2. Is there any other method apart from spool that can be used to generate files in Oracle?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "the data gets mixed" mean?  My guess is that you have certain rows that have issues-- perhaps you have data which includes commas or which is too long for the field so that the problem is not the number of rows but whether you happen to try to generate data for a "bad" row.  The fix, then, will depend on what is "bad" about that particular row.  You could use `utl_file` or any number of other tools to generate the file but it's not clear that this would have any benefit to you.

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanks for the quick response. When I say data gets mixed means, some rows don't contain data where a static string for columns data has been placed as default values. I doubt there is bad data, i will check though. The output of the inner query shows data availability in all columns prior to concatenation.